# How can I limit a views_pre_render() to a specific display of a view?

Tags: views, hooks

I have a views_pre_render() hook that I want to limit to a specific views display.

So far, [based on this code,](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/71402/5147) I have this:

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name=='VIEWNAME') {
    // ...
  }
}
```

However, I want to limit execution not to a specific view but to a specific display within that view.  I know the machine name of the display, but how do I incorporate that into the if statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like so:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_render().
 */
function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'VIEWNAME' && $view->current_display == 'DISPLAY_NAME') {
    // Do your thing here.
  }
}
```